# Spring security getting 403 although permitAll is there?

Tags: spring-security

I am working on a spring project with security using @EnableWebSecurity
when I enable csrf I am getting 403
although anything should be accepted:  antMatchers("/**").permitAll()  is there:

**Not working:**

```
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
```

this is the error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-18T13:43:43.098+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/api/checkPrinter"
}
```

**Working:**

```
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
```

We still want to have csrf protection ,
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you are trying to post? CRSF Is enabled by default and requires the Crsf token to be provided